# how to find index of array using substring value in javascript and replace with a new string?

Tags: javascript

I am getting string -

```
["1-2","10-4","2-3","3-1","4-4","5-2","6-4","7-3","8-1","9-2"]
```

as output from `GetOption` function where event - QuestionID & event1 -OptionID

Project-Online Examination System

```
var getValue;
var getName = new Array();
var temp = new Array();

function GetOption(event, event1) {
   debugger;

   if (temp.includes(event)) {
      var x = getName.indexOf(event);
      getName.splice(x - 1, 1);
      getName.includes(event);
   }

   this.event1 = event1;
   temp.push(event);

   var getValue = event + "-" + event1;

   if (getValue == "undefined-undefined") {
      getName.push("");
   } else {
      getName.push(getValue);
      getName.sort();
      alert(getName);
   }

   $("#resultHidden").val(getName);
}
```

Comment: What is the input? What is the expected output? Why are `C#` and `asp.net` tagged? Please create a [mcve] with a clear problem statement.

Comment: Input depends on users -no. of question and option selected, the output is like - "QuestionID-OptionID", I'm working on asp.net project.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please offer a minimal complete and verifiable example for people to help you. In this case, an expected input, and some explanation of what you are trying to accomplish would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
var items = ["1-2","10-4","2-3","3-1","4-4","5-2","6-4","7-3","8-1","9-2"];
var searchItems = "1-2";
var newItems = "2-1";
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].startsWith(searchItems)) {
        items[i] = newItems;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response, but it's not completely working  I have searchitems as "1" not "1-2" i need to modify the "2" .From your code previous value  remains in the same place and new value is appended after it